# SQL Azure equivalent

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I'm using Windows Azure now, but soon I must leave cloud and relocate my resources on local machines. There are SQL Azure db in my project. I want to know how to choose SQL Server machine. How much cores abd RAM should I take to replace S3 database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft have not provided official hardware mappings to service tier,but [few people were able to derive some sort of mappings](https://sqlperformance.com/2017/03/azure/what-the-heck-is-a-dtu)

Below chart shows some rough mappings
[image]

When you are hosting your database in onpremises, you might have to add more than what above chart shows,since you will have to account for  OS  as well..and can incur more costs due to windows and sql licences

Start with what you can and try adding more,if you face any performance issues